# Call listener from script when listener is in the background.js - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I create my extension.

I create a content.js file that inject in the page my "script".

```
 var SE = document.createElement('script');
  SE.src = chrome.extension.getURL('SE.js');
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(SE);
```

in the SE.js file I get this script. In my seExtID it's my chrome extension ID because if i do not pass the seExtID i get this error :

***Uncaught Error: chrome.runtime.connect() called from a webpage must specify an Extension ID (string) for its first argument***

So i pass my extentionID to the sendMessage method

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(seExtID, {
      method: "LoadSettings"
    },
      function (config) {
        defaultSettings = config;
      });
```

in my background.js file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      debugger;
      switch(request.method){
        case "SaveSettings":
          var se_json = request.settings;
          localStorage.setItem("se_settings", se_json);
          break;
        case "LoadSettings":
          var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("se_settings"));
          sendResponse(obj);
          break;
      }


    }
);
```

The problem is, if i call my SendMessage from the default_popup or from the content.js it's work.

In the content.js or in the default_popup, probably the context of the execution already exists, so the seExtID is not needed. I can call my send message witout the seExtID like and it's work :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage( {
      method: "LoadSettings"
    },
      function (config) {
        defaultSettings = config;
      });
```

If i take a look on the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage

string  (optional) extensionId

The ID of the extension/app to send the message to. If omitted, the message will be sent to your own extension/app. Required if sending messages from a web page for web messaging.

I probably miss something ... someone could help me on this one ?

Comment: `But i don't need to pass the seExtID if i pass the extention ID it's not work.` I don't understand your English in this sentence(and I think it is the core point of your question), could you clarify?

Comment: @KarlReid sorry for my english. I "rewrite" the sentence. is it better like that ?

Comment: Ok. The reason you get the error is because your `SE.js` script is not running within the context of your extension- it is part of the webpage since you injected it using a script tag, instead of using a content script(which are connected to the extension). Since it is has no context for the extension, Chrome doesn't know what the id should default to, so you need to specify it.

Comment: @KarlReid, the problem is when i specify it, it's not working. The script run inside my web page should be able to call extension context ?

Comment: No, you need a different listener: chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal